# beautifulsoup returns None for any element I try

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm building a fully automated get-a-job application, funny enough the automation portion is fairly simple, however the scrapping not so much.

In short, `requests` + `beautifulsoup` has worked for the majority of domains I am scrapping, however nothing works when trying the same process on *workable* pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = requests.Session()
url = 'https://apply.workable.com/breederdao-1/j/602097ACC9/'
req = session.get(url)

title = soup.find('h1', {'data-ui': 'job-title'})
print(title)

>>> None

details = soup.find('span', {'data-ui': 'job-location'})
print(details)

>>> None
```

Both elements are under `body`, however when I try to fetch the page's title I do get what I expect:

```
title_0 = soup.find('title')
print(title_0)

>>> <title>Data Analyst (Fully Remote) - BreederDAO</title>
```

I tried using `await` + `HTMLSEssion` / `AsyncHTMLSession` as well, but so long as the element is inside of `body`, every `find()` still returns `None`.

Can anyone educate me on this? My current hypothesis is that the website has some kind of anti-scrapping mechanism, but I have zero idea where to even start looking. This element does look extra sus though:

```
<html...
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    .
    .
    .
    <noscript>
      <iframe height="0" width="0" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WKS7WTT&amp;gtm_auth=SGnzIn3pcB7S4fevFXOKPQ&amp;gtm_preview=env-2&amp;gtm_cookies_win=x" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
        #document
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>ns</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              " "
            </body>
          </html>
      </iframe>
    </noscript>
    .
    .
    .
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via javascript. To load it you can use `requests` module. For example:

```py
import json
import requests


# 602097ACC9 is from your URL
url = "https://apply.workable.com/api/v2/accounts/breederdao-1/jobs/602097ACC9"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["title"])
print(", ".join(data["location"].values()))
```

Prints:

```
Data Analyst (Fully Remote)
Philippines, PH, Makati, Metro Manila
```